# Will the C# compiler optimise away my code readability measures?

Tags: c#, compilation

Sometimes I get highly repetitive blocks of code especially when dealing with DAL code.

For instance:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@CName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = c.Name.DisplayName;
command.Parameters.Add("@LKey", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15).Value = c.Alf;
command.Parameters.Add("@SalesTerritoryId", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15).Value = c.Profile.SalesTerritoryId;
command.Parameters.Add("@CAQ", SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value = (short)c.Profile.Quadrant;
```

Back in VB there was the With statement that could nicely tidy things up. Occasionally in C# I will do something like:

```
var cp = command.Parameters;
cp.Add("@CName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = c.Name.DisplayName;
cp.Add("@LKey", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15).Value = c.Alf;
cp.Add("@SalesTerritoryId", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15).Value = c.Profile.SalesTerritoryId;
cp.Add("@CAQ", SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value = (short)c.Profile.Quadrant;
```

Personally I find this to be more readable but I'm wondering if when compiled, do both versions become the same IL, in that the compiler is smart enough to know what I've done and simply optimises it away?

Or does cp stick around as  a useless reference post compilation?

Comment: This is the job of the jitter optimizer, not the C# compiler.  It just doesn't make any difference whether it optimizes that or not, the amount of overhead in the Parameters.Add() method far outstrips micro-optimizations like that.  Clearly helping the jitter doesn't hurt, not in readability either.

Comment: Does it really matter? Did you find that this code was causing performance issues? If not, move on to something important.

Comment: I *think* your more readable one is actually better anyway as it doesn't have to dereference `command.Parameters` for each one. Not sure at what point the cost of creating the variable counteracts any gain though.

Comment: @spender For performance, not that I can tell and I will probably never write apps for which it does. But knowing the answer to this question may help me to understand something else at another time. I ask a lot of things just out of curiosity.

Comment: The JIT compiler is likely to inline the call to `command.get_Parameters()`.

Comment: It's even not guaranteed that compiling the _same_ code twice results in the same IL. Let the compiler do the optimizations, it can do it much better then we mortals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in compiled form it will stay the same. (I haven't tried any optimization switches, just plain old release build). Question is what ngen will do to MSIL, but as far as MSIL is concerned, it does matter.

```
static void foo() {
  var command = new SqlCommand();
  command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "";
}

static void bar() {
  var command = new SqlCommand();
  var cp = command.Parameters;
  cp.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "";
}
```

Foo:

```
    .method private hidebysig static void  foo() cil managed
{
  // Code size       37 (0x25)
  .maxstack  4
  .locals init ([0] class [System.Data]System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command)
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void [System.Data]System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  IL_0006:  ldloc.0
  IL_0007:  callvirt   instance class [System.Data]System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection [System.Data]System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand::get_Parameters()
  IL_000c:  ldstr      "@Name"
  IL_0011:  ldc.i4.s   12
  IL_0013:  ldc.i4.s   50
  IL_0015:  callvirt   instance class [System.Data]System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter [System.Data]System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection::Add(string,
                                                                                                                                                     valuetype [System.Data]System.Data.SqlDbType,
                                                                                                                                                     int32)
  IL_001a:  ldstr      ""
  IL_001f:  callvirt   instance void [System.Data]System.Data.Common.DbParameter::set_Value(object)
  IL_0024:  ret
} // end of method Program::foo
```

Bar:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  bar() cil managed
{
  // Code size       39 (0x27)
  .maxstack  4
  .locals init ([0] class [System.Data]System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command,
           [1] class [System.Data]System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection cp)
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void [System.Data]System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  IL_0006:  ldloc.0
  IL_0007:  callvirt   instance class [System.Data]System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection [System.Data]System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand::get_Parameters()
  IL_000c:  stloc.1
  IL_000d:  ldloc.1
  IL_000e:  ldstr      "@Name"
  IL_0013:  ldc.i4.s   12
  IL_0015:  ldc.i4.s   50
  IL_0017:  callvirt   instance class [System.Data]System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter [System.Data]System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection::Add(string,
                                                                                                                                                     valuetype [System.Data]System.Data.SqlDbType,
                                                                                                                                                     int32)
  IL_001c:  ldstr      ""
  IL_0021:  callvirt   instance void [System.Data]System.Data.Common.DbParameter::set_Value(object)
  IL_0026:  ret
} // end of method Program::bar
```

Comment: Right, so I am introducing noise/artifacts. Thx.

Comment: @rism: Programmers frequently introduce "noise/artifacts" into their code in order to make it more readable/maintainable when they return to it. Your example is an idiomatic example of the introduction of such "noise". IMO, this isn't noise, and the few extra opcodes generated by the latter example are a tiny price to pay for the enhanced readability gained by storing commonalities in variables. As far as I'm concerned, your first example is likely to introduce noise in the brain of the next person who reads the code. Favor ease of readability over worries about the generation of minimal IL.

Comment: @spender Totally agree. People > machines.

Comment: @rism: It's also entirely possible (even likely) that the cost of looking up property `command.Parameters` is costly. In this case, storing a local reference might generate more IL, but actually causes less work.